# How do i redirect a non-existent folder to similar folder?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am creating a website where I want the members profile links as follows:

somedomain.com/someuser1/ -> somedomain.com/#!/home/someuser1/

somedomain.com/someuser2/ -> somedomain.com/#!/home/someuser2/
etc...

because i don't want to fill the root folder up with a bunch of member profile folders.  Can this be done easily in the .htaccess file with rewrites?

I believe i would need to pull the 'someuser1' and 'someuser2' values and append them during the rewrite, but i'm not sure how to do that...  the member folders will exist in the /home/ folder, but not the root folder...

Thanks!
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /#!/home/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Put this in the .htaccess file. Untested

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /#!/home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  The usernames won't always start with 'someuser'...  usernames could be 'bill' or 'jane', etc...  somedomain.com/bill -> somedomain.com/#!/home/bill, somedomain.com/jane -> somedomain.com/#!/home/jane...  Thanks!  Greg

Comment: Seem to be getting closer, but it's returning 'http://somedomain.com/%23!/home/%23!' in the browser (telling me there's a redirect loop). My current .htaccess is - RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /#!/home/$1 [R=301,NC,L]